# Liferay Carousel Portal Layout

Tags: jquery, liferay, liferay-theme

I'm developing a custom layout for Liferay Portal.

I would like to create something like some plugins used to show images as a carousel, however I would like to show the pages of the portal instead of images.

I create a template with 2 rows and 3 columns. Each page of my portal will be this format.

I create some pages with some portlets and in my main page, I show this pages like a carousel.

Any one knows if there is some plugin for this? Or can give a suggestion of how to build this?

I'm trying to use [Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) Plugin to build, but it is not being a easy thing to do.

in a few words, I would like to show pages instead of images in a carousel way

Comment: In the carousel, do you really want to show portal pages? For me, it would make more sense to show journal articles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The answer assumes you want to implement a carousel for web content / journal articles (not portal pages) in Liferay 6.2 (or later version).*

Liferay 6.2 introduces the framework for [Application Display Templates (ADT)](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/user-guide/-/ai/using-application-display-templates-liferay-portal-6-2-user-guide-07-en). ADTs can be used to customize the presentation of assets in various portlets. For example, you can customize the presentation of journal articles, documents or images in Asset Publisher or Media Gallery portlets. ADTs can be implemented using Freemarker or Velocity engines.

For images in Media Gallery, there's even a sample carousel template included in Liferay 6.2. See [portlet_display_template_carousel.ftl](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portlet/documentlibrary/dependencies/portlet_display_template_carousel.ftl) . The template uses [Alloy UI Carousel](http://alloyui.com/tutorials/carousel/) to implement the carousel. The template can be altered easily to implements the carousel for journal articles using your preferred Slick framework.

I suggest the following:

- Use web content / journal articles to create the slides for your carousel.
- Tag the articles with a defined tag.
- Create a new ADT to display the articles in a carousel.
- Utilize Asset Publisher portlet to display the articles.
- Configure the Asset Publisher to filter the articles by the defined tag a select your ADT template to display them.
- Done.